# How do I merge 3 Rooms together?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I keep on trying to merge 3 rooms but 1 makes a different one! Do I have to wait later in the game?

Answer (score 34):

The rooms must be of the same type, upgraded to the same level and placed next to each other horizontally (with no gaps) in order to merge into each other. It is possible to build rooms of the same type but different upgrade levels next to each other and these will subsequently merge when they're upgraded to the same level.

Answer (score 7):

I would also add that the rooms must be adjacent horizontally (not vertically), as that particular issue tripped me up the first find I tried to merge rooms in the game.

Comment: Same for me here :)

Comment: But you would just fall through the floor...

Comment: @JoshSpoors. Not if you have floors and stairs. Too bad there are no such things as stairs in Shelter...

Comment: or a slide perhaps?

Comment: @joshSpoors you'd think that if a vault can handle an elevator, then stairs should be as easy as Molerat Pie (not a Fallout item, but it should be).

Comment: I'll have one slice of strawberry tart without so much molerat in it.